# C# asp dotNet - Convert Datetime field to Date/String

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, dataset

I find myself unable to change the stored procedure, which produces a datetime field (among other fields) , but I want to display the datetime field in my gridview as either Date (MM/DD/YYYY) or a string in the same format (similar to SQL's: CONVERT(VARCHAR,[datetimeField],101)).

I have pulled the dataset but don't see any way to convert it for this specific field after pulling it, so it shows the time too. I welcome any advice. Here are pieces from my code:

**aspx.cs:**

```
    DataSet ds = RunSQLString("SplitItemsDesc_Get '" + ddlSearchItem.Text + "', 'C7'", lsreplenDBConnection);
    if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView2.DataBind();
        GridView2.Visible = true;
        btnReset.Visible = true;
    }
```

**aspx gridview:**

```
  <asp:gridview id="GridView1" autogeneratecolumns="False" EmptyDataText="Saved Record(s) not found" runat="server"
     Font-Size="10pt" Font-Names="Verdana" cellpadding="3" CellSpacing="0" BorderWidth="2" BorderColor="#5F6366" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#D8E0E2" ForeColor="#0A2D3B"
     OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting">
       <columns>
          <%--other fields here--%>
          <asp:TemplateField headertext="End Date">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:label id="endDate"
                                Text= '<%# Eval("end_date") %>'
                                runat="server"
                                Width="378px"/> 
                </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
       </columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Answer (score 0):

Of course after I post it, after searching for answer prior, I find the solution:

```
Text='<%# Eval("end_date", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>'
```

We're good. Rubber Ducky debugging has concluded.